# Relative url in HTML

Tags: html, relative-path

I have two applications called `cdf` and `dasauth` from dasauth application landing.htm file m calling

`href="/careerdevelopment/WebContent/JSP/matrix.jsp "` 
using relative path its not working.

However, it does work if I use an absolute path as seen below.

`href="http://localhost:8080/careerdevelopment/WebContent/JSP/matrix.jsp"`

I think this is due to the scope of the file in different project. Is it possible to can run this application using only relative paths?

Comment: "its not working" — In what way is it not working? What URL is actually being requested? What is the URL of the document the `href` appears in?

Comment: ... and what do you mean by relative? Because an href starting with "/" is not relative in my book :)

Comment: @Gerard van Helden an href starting with "/" is relative within the application. The absolute url contains the protocol (not always) the domain, the port, things like those..  #kiran rathod - if you need to link to another project in different domain (or port or protocol) you have to use an absolute href.

Comment: Hm, yeah that's a bit of semantics I stand corrected on :) It is a relative URL,  but it is not a relative path.

Comment: domain is same for both mean running on same server and both have same domain (port or protocol)

Comment: @kiran, can you tell us what is the address in your browser? (I guess it is something that doesn't begin with http://localhost:8080 )